# forcefully bundle update in heroku rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

Let's say I have 2 codebases/git repos. `project A and gem B`.

project A uses gem B.

Here is the entry in the project A Gemfile.

`gem 'B', git: 'https://yashdfjwehrlhkhklbRrKwgNq:x-token-auth@bitbucket.org/pwa-abcde/B.git', branch: 'dev/B-api'`

Now today I made some changes to `gem B` and pushed it to git.

But `project A` never gets this update as it is already using the old version of the gem.

My main project(A) is hosted in heroku.

Now my doubt is how can I force heroku to fetch the latest changes for the gem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it in below two ways:

1. set `ref` that represent commit hash in your Gemfile instead of `branch` name and run bundle install. Now when you push again to heroku it will fetch right commmit.

   ```
   gem 'B', git: 'https://yashdfjwehrlhkhklbRrKwgNq:x-token-auth@bitbucket.org/pwa-abcde/B.git', ref: 'commmit-hash'
   ```
2. Create new branch for your commit for `gem B` changes and set new branch.

This is happening because you didn't pusdev/B-apih any change in Gemfile. Heroku run `bundle install` if there is any change in `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: Sounds logical, I will try the same. So each time we modify something in the gem, we need to provide the commit hash in our project gemfile?

Comment: Seems to be working fine. But what is the best practise for production environment. Do we need to give the commit hash every time we  make some changes?

Comment: We didn't make changes in gem very frequently so, better to generate branch and set head. If gem is your own then you can create new version each time.

Comment: You can accept answer if it solved your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running `bundle update` within `Project A` at Heroku, run `bundle update` locally first. This will update your `Gemfile.lock`. Test if the `Project A` still runs locally as expected.
Then commit and push the new `Gemfile.lock` to Heroku.

Comment: Already tried the same, it will not work because it will use the existing gem instead of fetching the new version from the git.

Comment: It would've worked if the `Gemfile.lock` was generated from a Windows system. Nevermind, I've re-written the answer to what I feel is the better way to go about this scenario.